# Cannot connect to data when customizing form (in PowerApps) from a SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

After creating a list on SharePoint Online, I clicked on "Customize forms" under PowerApps in order to create a form with conditional branches. However, once it loads, the following error comes up:

[image: error message]

I contacted Microsoft Support, specifically PowerApps however I did not receive much help. Any advice on where the issue lies will be greatly appreciated.

notes:

- I have full control over this site and list
- I tried creating a test list with just 2 simple columns and it still gave me the same error.
- I tried another Microsoft account to access it as well. Still the same error.

Comment: See the logs corresponding to the correlation ID for detailed error.

Comment: This is what shows up in dev tools - console: HTTP401: DENIED - The requested resource requires user authentication.
(XHR)POST - https://api.powerapps.com/api/invoke

Answer (score 0):

You could check the office 365 version and check if you have enabled PowerApps for the user.

Go to active users->select and click the user->Edit the product licenses.

[image]